# Creating xml doc with python/ElementTree and namespaces

Tags: python, elementtree

I'm trying to create an in-memory xml document such that the root's child nodes all require a name space.

The final document should look something like this:

```
<Feed>            
<FeedEntity Id="0000" 
      xmlns="http://schemas.example.com/search/query/2010/5/revision">

    <FeedRequest locale="en-US" title="<some value>"/>
</FeedEntity>
... another FeedEntity element ...
</Feed>
```

However, when I print out the document I've created with ElementTree lib, it looks more like this:

```
<Feed>
    <ns0:FeedEntity Id="0000"
      xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.example.com/search/query/2010/5/revision">

        <FeedRequest locale="en-US" title="<some value>"/>
    </ns0:FeedEntity>
</Feed>
```

Here's how I'm creating the document:

```
counter = 0
namespace = "http://schemas.example.com/search/query/2010/5/revision"

root = Element("Feed")        

node_name = "{%s}FeedEntity" % (namespace, );                
feed_entity_element = Element(node_name)        

feed_entity_element["Id"] = "%04d" % (counter,);

feed_request_element = Element("FeedRequest");
feed_request_element["Culture"] = self.culture;
feed_request_element["Query"] = address;        

# append each of the elements to the xml document 
feed_entity_element.append(feed_request_element);

root.append(feed_entity_element);

str_data = ET.tostring(root)
print str_data
```

How do I get rid of the "ns0" parts in the final XML so it looks more like the first example noted above?

Comment: Why do you want to change it - anything using XML should treat the two versions the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `xml.etree`, you cannot get the exact output as in the first example, but you can use the (global) [register_namespace()](http://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.register_namespace) function to use a "better" prefix than "ns0". For example: `ET.register_namespace('rev', 'http://schemas.example.com/search/query/2010/5/revision')` will make sure the output will look like `rev:FeedEntity`.

The (compatible) [lxml](http://lxml.de/) library, however, is more flexible with regard to namespace prefixes, and [allows you to provide a prefix mapping when creating an element](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#namespaces).

Comment: Turns out that you can also assign the attribute 'xmlns' for the element and it will produce the same xml string output.